# Using Customized Pyinstaller .spec file with PyArmor

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pyinstaller, pyarmor

If my Python 2 script has been packed using PyInstaller 4.3 using a customized `.spec` file and with the command

```
pyinstaller foo.spec
```

how do we use PyArmor 6.7.2 to pack the same Python script using the same `.spec` file?

Running the following command

```
pyarmor pack --name Foo -e '--onefile foo.spec' start.py
```

results in the error

> makespec.py: error: unrecognized arguments: ./start.py

How can we fix this?

---

**PyArmor output:**

Why is it still trying to generate another .spec file?

```
...

INFO     Found runtime module pytransform.py
INFO     Copy dist/obf/pytransform.py to temp path
INFO     Run PyInstaller to generate .spec file...
INFO     

/opt/anaconda3/envs/foo/bin/python -m PyInstaller.utils.cliutils.makespec --onefile foo.spec --name Foo -p dist/obf/temp --hidden-import pytransform --additional-hooks-dir dist/obf/temp ./start.py


INFO     ==================== Run command ====================
usage: makespec.py [-h] [-D] [-F] [--specpath DIR] [-n NAME] [--add-data <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>] [--add-binary <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>] [-p DIR] [--hidden-import MODULENAME] [--collect-submodules MODULENAME] [--collect-data MODULENAME]
                   [--collect-binaries MODULENAME] [--collect-all MODULENAME] [--copy-metadata PACKAGENAME] [--additional-hooks-dir HOOKSPATH] [--runtime-hook RUNTIME_HOOKS] [--exclude-module EXCLUDES] [--key KEY]
                   [-d {all,imports,bootloader,noarchive}] [-s] [--noupx] [--upx-exclude FILE] [-c] [-w] [-i <FILE.ico or FILE.exe,ID or FILE.icns or "NONE">] [--version-file FILE] [-m <FILE or XML>] [-r RESOURCE] [--uac-admin]
                   [--uac-uiaccess] [--win-private-assemblies] [--win-no-prefer-redirects] [--osx-bundle-identifier BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER] [--runtime-tmpdir PATH] [--bootloader-ignore-signals] [--log-level LEVEL]
                   scriptname [scriptname ...]
makespec.py: error: unrecognized arguments: ./start.py
INFO     ==================== End command ====================

ERROR    Run command failed
```

**foo.spec:**

```
...

a = Analysis(['start.py'],
             pathex=['/home/x/test'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=datas,
             hiddenimports=hiddenimports,
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='foo',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='start')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your .spec already is configured to --onefile, you don't need specify it again in the command. Just do:

```
pyarmor pack -s foo.spec foo.py
```

The -s tag is to specify .spec files, like explains here:

https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/man.html

Answer (score 0):

PyArmor 8.0+

```
pyinstaller -F foo.py
pyarmor gen -O obfdist --pack dist/foo.exe foo.py
```

Reference: https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/obfuscation.html#packing-to-one-folder